# Can't dual boot Windows 7 and Linux Kali

Tags: linux, dual-boot, kali-linux

Long story short, I don't want to / can't use Kali on a VM properly. I want to set up a dual boot machine. I've done the following:

1. I downloaded the Kali ISO and used [Win32DiskImager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) to put it onto my
   Usb.
2. I restarted it and went to the boot menu (F8 for me) and selected my
   USB drive.

It just went straight to the windows start-up menu (Safe Mode, etc.) I tried with a different USB and same result - also with a different program. Then with disk but it was not recognized at all. What shall I do? Please Help ASAP. I've been dealing with this issue for 6 days straight.

Comment: F8 is not the correct Key for your BIOS, it is the correct key for the Safe Mode Menu. Try F2, F11, or Del.  Select Advanced, Boot Order and set the first device to USB HDD, the second to CD-ROM, and the last to your HDD.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you have to go into the computer BIOS to select the boot order. You have to give priority to your USB over the HD. This way Kali will be booted.

When you pressed F8, you went into the Windows start-up menu as you mentioned. This is already too late because it is not a proper boot loader for Kali Linux. IF you are able to provide more details on your Hardware I can try to search what is the key to access the computer BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps for best result

- If you have any preinstalled linux use dd (dd if=kali.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k) for best result
- Burn you ISO to USB with win32 disk imaage or kind of tool.
- Ideally it should be detect USB and and boot it.
- If not then go to BIOS setting and set 1st boot device to USB
- It will work smoothly .

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue with Kali and Windows 8.1. What did the trick for me was downloading bootrepair, setting it up as a bootable USB drive, booting into it and following the prompts. It reconfigured some things and now my system boots in GRUB letting me choose from Kali and Windows. Here is the bootrepair I used: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

- Edit you may have to access BIOS menu to change boot sequence to avoid windows from blocking the bootrepair + kali from booting.